# jquery no emite mensaje de validacion

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, jquery-validate

Hola un cordial saludo a la comunidad, el dia de hoy les traigo un problema nuevo el cual trata de una validación simple con plugin de jquery.validate, el asunto es el siguiente tengo mi formulario en html :

```
<div class="container" align="center"><br>
  <fieldset><br>
    <legend>Busqueda Participantes</legend>
    <form class="form-inline" method="post" id="participantes" name="participantes">
      <div>

          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula" name="cedula" id="cedula">         
          <input type="hidden" name="buscar" id="buscar">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary" name="buscar" id="buscar">      
      </div>    
    </form><br>
  </fieldset><br>
</div>
```

---

### y en otro lado mi script con el codigo de jquery validate para validar el campo cedula

```
$(function(){
    //$(document).ready(function(){
    //$(document).on("ready",function(){
    $("#participantes").on("click",function(){
        $("#buscar").validate
        //errorClass: "error",
        alert("LLega hasta aqui");
        ({
            rules:
            {
                cedula:{required:true,number:true,min:100000,max:99999999}
            },
            messages:
            {
                cedula:{required:'Campo Requerido',min:'Minimo 6 numeros',max:'Maximo 8 Numeros',number:'Solo Numeros'}
            }
        });
    });
});
```

el asunto es que el llega hasta el alert("LLega hasta aqui"); pero no se porque razon no me ejecuta los mensajes de validacion que deberia mostar ya he intentado de todo y no se que hacer, por favor si alguien sabe la respuesta a esta pregunta ele estare muy agradecido.

Comment: En la consola del navegador no muestra ningun error?

Comment: no muestra nada

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregarle `submitHandler` para ejecutar el llamado ( asi me funciono a mi )

```
$("#participantes").on("click",function(){
  $("#buscar").validate({
    rules:{
     cedula:{required:true,number:true,min:100000,max:99999999}
    },
   messages:{
     cedula:{required:'Campo Requerido',min:'Minimo 6 numeros',max:'Maximo 8 Numeros',number:'Solo Numeros'}
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: he checho otros formularios con esta estructura y me funciona, pero voy a probar con submitHandler ya que no he probado con eso a ver como me va

Comment: nada aun persiste la problematica no emite mensajes .....

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos errores. Uno de concepto y otro de código:

- **Concepto**: El método `validate` no tiene que ser invocado en el evento `click` sino en el `load`. Digamos que de esa forma estás asignado las reglas de validación a tu formulario al cargar el DOM.
- **Código**: Por otro lado, tu `form` es `participantes` y tu botón `buscar` y los estás llamando al revés.

Te dejo una [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s6qyLmcc/) funcionando. Como ves elimino el click ya que no es necesario:

```js
$(function(){
    //$(document).ready(function(){
    //$(document).on("ready",function(){
    $("#participantes").validate({
            rules:
            {
                cedula:{required:true,number:true,min:100000,max:99999999}
            },
            messages:
            {
                cedula:{required:'Campo Requerido',min:'Minimo 6 numeros',max:'Maximo 8 Numeros',number:'Solo Numeros'}
            }
        });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div class="container" align="center"><br>
  <fieldset><br>
    <legend>Busqueda Participantes</legend>
    <form class="form-inline" method="post" id="participantes" name="participantes">
      <div>

          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula" name="cedula" id="cedula">         
          <input type="hidden" name="buscar" id="buscar">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary" name="buscar" id="buscar">      
      </div>    
    </form><br>
  </fieldset><br>
</div>
```